UDP send rate on F1 UDP and Serial Port
Im building an steering wheel to play F1 codemasters games.
Those games have the option to send telemetry through UDP.
https://answers.ea.com/t5/General-Discussion/F1-23-UDP-Specification/td-p/12632888

As shown, you can select an UDP send Rate (from 10Hz to 120Hz)
Im sending the UDP to the same PC (IP 127.0.0.1) And I have coded a net c# console app that gets the data and then sends it through an usb-ttl converter to a nextion screen and to a esp32 to blink leds.
public static readonly SerialPort serialPort = new("COM7", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
            {
                Handshake = Handshake.None
            };

public static void NextionPrepare(string s)
        {
            var commandBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s);
            var terminatorBytes = new byte[] {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};
            combinedBytes.AddRange(commandBytes.Concat(terminatorBytes));
        }

public static void SendNextion()
        {
            serialPort.Write(combinedBytes.ToArray(), 0, combinedBytes.Count);
            combinedBytes.Clear();
        }

That piece of code creates the serialport connection and sends data when necessary. The led stuff is similar, just an .ino code to blink.
My problem is, if I set UDP Send Rate over 30Hz (60, 100 or 120Hz) screen and leds are delayed, like a second. If I use 30Hz or less it works perfectly.
So my question is, where is the problem?
Is the game not sending the correct amount of packets?
Is my code inefficient (or the programming language?
Has the serial port interface or the cp210x usb-ttl any limitation?
Im out of ideas, I have increased buffer sizes, but nothing changes.
Any clues?
thanks!

After some digging, changing the baudrate from 115200 to 921600 fixed the delay.
